# Lyx - editing the latex-code inside a math box or stop automatic converting in it

Tags: math-mode, lyx

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> creates a math box. I type something like `\cdot` and it is converted to natural symbols. How can I edit the Latex-code without copying+inserting it to somewhere out of the math box. Deleting and retyping is very annoying.
There must be a shortcut to switch between this two views?
Or is it possible to turn this automatically converting inside a math box off and do it manually or the other way round?

Note: The Option instant preview under tools/preferences/view & handle/view is already turned off (standard). This has nothing to do with the automatic math box converting.

Comment: Also note that LyX is not a good LaTeX editor (it's not meant to be). It is good at other things, but not at editing raw LaTeX. You might like one of the many good LaTeX editors better.

Comment: @scottkosty: I tried to make a shortcut for your command. But it doesn't work.
I insert "command-sequence char-forward; line-end-select ; cut; char-backward; paste; char-delete-forward`" in function and add a key combination. Do I forget something?

Comment: Can you add a shortcut for something else (try something simple)? Can you run that command on the mini-buffer (alt+x)?